# How to make cyrillic working with TeX Gyre fonts?

Tags: fonts, xetex, languages, cyrillic

I want to write a document in Russian language using XeLaTeX and TeX Gyre font (for example TEX Gyre Termes). According to docs here http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/qtm-info.pdf (pp. 3-4) it supports cyrillic letters, but I cannot make it working. What i've tried:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
    А это по-русски.
\end{document}
```

and

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
    А это по-русски.
\end{document}
```

(if i understand correctly, it is preffered to use `babel` instead of `polyglossia`)

But nothing is working. This is what I'm getting in output PDF:

[image: cyrillic letters are missing]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: From looking into the fonts, it seems that the information is not correct. Some "standard" fonts that have them are `stixtwo`, `dejavu`, `libertinus`, `ebgaramond`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite claiming that the `cyrl` language tag and the Cyrillic block 0x0400–0x04FF are supported, in the list of glyphs there's a jump from 0x03F5  to 0x0E3F.

I'm not sure whether the developers started thinking to add Cyrillic, but they actually didn't.

You can use Tempora that comes with the main TeX distributions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Tempora}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\begin{document}

Hello world!

А это по-русски.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use Stix Two, but the glyphs are slightly different from “standard” Times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{STIXTwoText}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]

\begin{document}

Hello world!

А это по-русски.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need a font with cyrillic, eg Times New Roman windows font

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[main=russian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
    А это по-русски.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for idea, i will use it if won't find another solution. As I understand this issue depends on font, but why does 'TeX Gyre Termes' not working? I've mentioned it in question that the docs say that this font support cyrillic. Is this information wrong?

Comment: I'm jusr looking but I think the doc is wrong, at least Termes doesn't seem to have this range @IgorMahov

Comment: @david-carlise, ok, thank you for explanation